# Unable to access domain shares, when connected to another network over OpenVPN

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, openvpn

Win 10. When logged in to our corporate network, I can access our domain shares and print to network printer (physically connected to another PC; shared). As soon as I connect to client's network over OpenVPN, I cannot access our domain resources.

The problem started to occur as soon as I upgraded to Windows 10 from Win7 (where this issue did not exist). Other people who upgraded at the same time do not have this issue, I'm the only one. Firewall is Off for all domain, private, and public networks. Windows defender is running, but no other antivirus is installed.

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this, or what could be the issue?

Comment: there are two possible problems: IP reachability and DNS resolution. If you can ping domain servers by IP, then its probably a DNS issue.  For IP. make sure you have Split-Tunneling enabled, so that your PC can access the local network for addresses that are available locally. https://support.vpnsecure.me/articles/frequently-asked-questions/openvpn-split-tunneling . for DNS, try connecting to the shares with the Fully Qualified Domain Name.

Comment: thanks! so, I can connect by IP, but not by name, including FQDN :(